# How do you print out elements from a Numpy array on new lines using a for loop?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Create an array with numpy and add elements to it. After you do this, print out all its elements on new lines.

I used the reshape function instead of a for loop. However, I know this would create problems in the long run if I changed my array values.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([0,5,69,5,1])

print(a.reshape(5,1))
```

How can I make this better? I think a for loop would be best in the long run but how would I implement it?

Answer (score 2):

Some options to print an array "vertically" are:

1. `print(a.reshape(-1, 1))` - You can pass *-1* as one dimension,
   meaning "expand this dimension to the needed extent".
2. `print(np.expand_dims(a, axis=1))` - Add an extra dimension, at the second place,
   so that each row will have a single item. Then print.
3. `print(a[:, None])` - Yet another way of reshaping the array.

Or if you want to print just **elements** of a **1-D** array in a column,
without any surrounding brackets, run just:

```
for x in a:
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
print(a.reshape([a.shape[0], 1]))
```

This will work regardless of how many numbers are in your numpy array.

Alternatively, you could also do this:

```
[print(number) for number in a.tolist()]
```

Comment: If you want to change from a row array to a column array better use a.reshape(-1,1)